# Ext4 FS: max file size

Tags: ext4

If I am not wrong, than with triple indirect addressing, the maximum file size for ext3 would be (4G+4M+4K).

Likewise, what will be the the maximum file size for an ext4 FS using extents if we assume a 4KB disk block size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BS = Block size = 4 KiB

You missed the 12 **direct** pointers in your calculation for ext3:

```
(12*BS = 48 KiB) + 4 MiB + 4 GiB + 4 TiB
```

For ext4, we use 32-bit indexing for the extents:

```
2^32 * (BS = 2^12) = 2^44 = 16 TiB
```

which is the number you would e.g. also find on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) for the maximum ext4 file size.